# How can I create a custom colour scale using ggplot2 and geom_tile?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to modify the colour gradient in order to match a set of predefined thresholds/cutpoints and colours. How can I do this?

Cutoff values: -0.103200,  0.007022, 0.094090,  0.548600 
Colors: "#EDF8E9", "#BAE4B3", "#74C476", "#238B45"

```
    #Create sample data

        pp <- function (n,r=4) {
              x <- seq(-r*pi, r*pi, len=n)
              df <- expand.grid(x=x, y=x)
              df$r <- sqrt(df$x^2 + df$y^2)
              df$z <- cos(df$r^2)*exp(-df$r/6)
              df
            }

            pp(20)->data

#create the plot

library(ggplo2)
            p <- ggplot(pp(20), aes(x=x,y=y))
            p + geom_tile(aes(fill=z))

#Generate custom colour ramp

library(RColorBrewer)

cols <- brewer.pal(4, "Greens")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may try `scale_fill_brewer`. First, bin your z values:

```
df <- pp(20)
df$z_bin <- cut(df$z, breaks = c(-Inf, -0.103200, 0.007022, 0.094090, 0.548600))
```

Plot:

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = x, y = y, fill = z_bin)) +
  geom_tile() +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Greens")
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Use `cut` and match the bins to your colors. My code assumes -0.103200 is minimum of your vector (to sort the number of bins).

```
trh <- c(-0.103200, 0.007022, 0.094090, 0.548600, Inf)
colors <- c("#EDF8E9", "#BAE4B3", "#74C476", "#238B45")

x <- runif(30, min = -0.103200, max = 1)
xc <- cut(x, breaks = trh)
colors[xc]
```

Comment: Using the sample data I provided, how should I use the code you provided?